# mongodb .find elements in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an array that dynamically holds document id's, in which I need to query another collcetion in mongo to see if the id's match. I have this code:

```
let collection = database.collection('login')

    let doc = await collection.find({ email: req.session.username }).toArray()

    let array_of_docs_bought = []
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
        array_of_docs_bought.push(doc[i].list_of_docs_bought)
    }


    let documents = await database.collection('documents').find({ "id": { $in: array_of_docs_bought } }).toArray()
```

however, doing `"id": { $in: array_of_docs_bought }` doesn't iterate through the array, so it returns nothing, but when I do this:

`let documents = await database.collection('documents').find({ "id": { $in: [ 'g81h8', '2ac3c', 'juc8d', 'g81h8', 'h9k2c' ] } }).toArray()`

it works, because values of the array are there and their isn't anything to iterate through. So how can I make it iterate through array_of_docs_bought, or reformat all the code all together if it makes more sense.

Comment: An alternative approach to the answer with the spread operator would be to use $lookup to do both find operations at the same time. localField would be list_of_docs_bought and foreignField would be id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_of_docs_bought.push(doc[i].list_of_docs_bought)` seems like the likely culprit here. Depending on the shape of your data you might be pushing arrays into your array, winding up with a nested array. This would be fixed via the 'spread operator':

```js
let array_of_docs_bought = []
for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
    array_of_docs_bought.push(...doc[i].list_of_docs_bought)
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that haha. Thanks, this worked!

Comment: @devofto Glad to hear that fixed it! Could you accept this answer by hitting the checkmark next to it? That way this question will appear as 'solved' on the main page for other people :)